# What stats of Malzahar's do the Voidlings mimic?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that the Voidlings scale 1.0 of Malzahar's Attack Damage, and partially from Armor Penetration, but do they benefit from anything else? And if they benefit from his life steal, does the life go to the Voidlings or Malzahar?

The reason I ask is because I want to use Surge with this build: http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/build/ad-malzahar-the-true-power-of-the-voidlings-197526 I'd cast Surge and use my ult and W so that I benefit from the additional AP while my Voidlings use the Attack Speed to dish out more damage.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, Surge is being removed.

Comment: Are you kidding me? I love using it for Elise :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the a better description of the ability in full. They only scale with your attack damage, unfortunately.

> A voidlings has 200 + (50 × level) health and 20 + (5 × level) + (100%
>   bonus AD) attack damage. After 7 seconds, the voidling grows, gaining
>   50% increased armor and base attack damage. After 14 seconds, the
>   voidling gains attack speed.
>
> ```
> Armor: 30 (45 after 7 seconds)
> Magic resistance: 50
> Attack speed: 0.831 (1.496 after 14 seconds)
> Movement speed: 451
> ```
>
> Voidlings prioritize the target of Nether Grasp, then enemies
>   suffering from the most recent Malefic Visions. If there are no
>   targets affected by Malefic Visions, it will attack Malzahar's target.

via [lolwiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Malzahar)

Answer (score 0):

Sad, but only Attack Damage, and Armor Penetration. But another aspects will boost you voidlings: **Max Mana**, **Mana Regen** and **Cooldown Reduction**. If you max these, you will turn Malzahar a Magic Machine (this alone will be a doom for your enemies), and it will maintain 2-3 voidlings in the field at same time!

Good Luck!